# What does the actual sort() function in c++ look like?

Tags: c++, function, standard-library

I was thinking about what would be the most efficient way to sort 100 natural numbers that are randomly placed in a vector. I came up with several solutions, but they all seemed horribly inefficient.

So I thought of looking up the actual sort() function in c++, but all I could find were questions about how to use the function, what it does, variations of it, but I couldn't find the actual function, the code that is written in the standard library.

Additionally, if anybody who knows how the function's code works were so kind to explain it, that would be great.